# EF 4.3 - Update entity and sub entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I have an entity Order with a sub entity OrderDetail. I want to update the Order and add a new OrderDetail. How should i do this?

I've tried setting the state of the Order to modified but i get this error:

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Update:
After i've added the new OrderDetail, i want to update the order type which is part of primary key. I've tried to set the state of OrderDetail to modified but i get a new error:

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the new `OrderDetail` into `Added` state first before you set the `Order` to `Modified`:

```cs
var newOrderDetail = order.OrderDetails.First();
context.Entry(newOrderDetail).State = EntityState.Added;
context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This might work - or not, depending on the details of your model and scenario...

Comment: This work for newly created OrderDetail but modifying part of the primary key, it doesn't work if i set the state to modified.

Comment: @sysboard: You cannot modify the primary key properties of an existing entity with EF. The key is the identity EF uses to find the row to update in the database. If you change the key EF doesn't find the row anymore you want to update. You can perform a key change only with direct SQL.